# Plotting time of day and location coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have to plot data that have DateTime and GPS coordinate information. As an example:

```
2013-03-01 19:55:00     45.4565    65.6783
2013-03-01 01:40:00     46.3121    -12.3456
2013-03-02 11:25:00     23.1234    -85.3456
2013-03-05 05:00:00     15.4565    32.1234
......
```

This is just a random example matching the type of data I have. The whole data set is for a week and the timestamps are rounded to the nearest 5 minutes.

What I would like to do in python is to visualize this data for location patterns for each 24 hour period for the entire week. So, x-axis would have time of day. I am struggling to thing about how the location would be shown. May be a 3D plot is needed.

It would show each day in a different color and also one more for an average of the entire week (i.e. the whole week averaged into a 24 hour period).

Any idea how one would go about visualizing this using python and matplotlib?

Note that I cannot plot the locations of an actual map for now. But just as (x,y) co-ordinates.

Comment: Should all days be in 1 plot? You could make a scatter with coloring by the timestamp. Or perhaps create a grid of subplots with 'small multiples' per day. How many entries do you have? Are 1 or 2 entries per day a realistic example?

Comment: @RutgerKassies not necessarily. but I want to compare the location pattern for different days of the week. the basic problem is to do it for one day I guess. I have one entry for every 5 minute for each hour of each day. The example only shows the data format. What I need to learn is what is a good way to visualize this data and do it in python :)

Answer (score 2):

Try using Folium's HeatMap with Time. 
First you define a function to generate the map.

```
def generateBaseMap(default_location, default_zoom_start=12):
    base_map = folium.Map(location=default_location, control_scale=True, zoom_start=default_zoom_start)
    return base_map
```

Then you add latitude and longitudes in a list which is ordered by date.

```
date_list = []
for date in df.date.sort_values().unique():
    date_list.append(df.loc[df.date == date, ['lat', 'lng']].values.tolist())
```

Then you plot the Heat Map with Time

```
from folium.plugins import HeatMapWithTime

base_map = generateBaseMap(default_zoom_start=11, default_location = [lat, longitude])
HeatMapWithTime(date_list, radius=5, gradient={0.2: 'blue', 0.4: 'lime', 0.6: 'orange', 1: 'red'}, min_opacity=0.5, max_opacity=0.8, use_local_extrema=True).add_to(base_map)
base_map
```

Hope this helps.